# Bad state: Future already completed calling for unknown reason

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error sometimes in my app, but I'm unsure of its origin because this is all it provides me with

```
I/flutter (10601): #0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
I/flutter (10601): #1      Route.didComplete (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:189:19)
I/flutter (10601): #2      NavigatorState.pushReplacement.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1846:13)
I/flutter (10601): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:389:15)
I/flutter (10601): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
I/flutter (10601): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
I/flutter (10601): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
I/flutter (10601): #7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
I/flutter (10601): #8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
I/flutter (10601): #9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
I/flutter (10601): #10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)
I/flutter (10601): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
I/flutter (10601): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
I/flutter (10601): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart
I/flutter (10601): Caught error: Bad state: Future already completed
```

I'm unsure why this was happening mostly because the logging is inadequate, but I think it may have something to do with the pushReplacementNamed function.

Comment: add the code you are using when you get the error

Comment: @diegoveloper that's just it, the error doesn't tell me what code is causing this

Comment: then add all of your code :D

Comment: @diegoveloper not really an option haha, on closer inspection it looks like that is coming from my `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/HomeScreen");`. For some reason it only throws sometimes though, not always

Comment: @Conner can you add the code where you used TickerProviderStateMixin?

Comment: also please add where you set routes/pages